# Get response/return value after a POST request (python requests)

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send an image to my API and then get results back from it. For example I send a bmp image file using

```
file = {"img": open("img.bmp)}
r = requests.post(url, files = file)
```

Now I'm getting stuck on how to read the result from the API.

Usually we have a data value we send to API and get results as

```
data = {"data":"MyDataString"}
r = requests.get(url, params = data)
```

But I need to send an Image. I tried looking for ways to send image in a GET request or use r.content with the POST request but couldn't make it work.

For better visualizing the problem here is an example:
Consider an API where you send an image and get the processed image in result.

Hopefully you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: POST requests shouldn't return anything besides return code.

Comment: You are right. But I want to send image in my request to get results from my Api. So either I read the results or send the image in a GET request somehow.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean in "to send image in my request to get results"? You can't send information over GET request, that's against the structure of API. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Imagine an Api where you send an image and get a processed image back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do the job. ( Sending and receiving image with a POST request)

While sending the file with same method as in question's POST request I receive the resulting image as a **base64** encoded string. I simply had to read it from `r.content` and decode.

**To Debug**
I used [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org) as my url in POST request to see the data I was sending.

i.e `r = requests.post("https://httpbin.org", files = file)`

**Solution**
For solving the problem I used the decode/encode methods according to this guide [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/base64-encoding-and-decoding-using-python--cms-25588#:%7E:text=To%20decode%20an%20image%20using,containing%20the%20resulting%20binary%20data.)

The answer by [Booboo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823719/booboo) helped me to find this solution.

Hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification to your program that posts your program to a URL and is expecting a BMP image back and writes the output to `stdout`, which you could redirect to a disk file. The point, however, is that the returned image is the byte stream `r.content`. Do what you want with it.

```
import requests
import sys

url = 'some-url'
with open("img.bmp", "rb") as f:
    file = {"img": f}
    r = requests.post(url, files=file)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(r.content)
```

Here is an example of a Python CGI program at URL "some-url". This just returns the original BMP:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys

cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form['img']
bmp = fileitem.file.read()

print('Content-Type: img/bmp\r\n\r\n', end='', flush=True)
# just send back the original image unmodified
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bmp)
```